# Как сделать словарь с одинаковыми ключами в Python?

Tags: python

Есть такой список:

```
panel_name = ["ЩК1.1", "ЩК1.1", "ЩК1.1", "ЩК1.1", "ЩК1.2", "ЩК1.2", "ЩК1.2", "ЩК1.3", "ЩК1.3"]
```

И надо пронумеровать по порядку элементы списка с одинаковыми значениями, типа так:

```
ЩК1.1: 1
ЩК1.1: 2
ЩК1.1: 3
ЩК1.1: 4
ЩК1.2: 1
ЩК1.2: 2
ЩК1.2: 3
ЩК1.3: 1
ЩК1.3: 2
```

Пытался сделать через словарь:

```
circuit_name = {}
for i in range(len(panel_name)):
    test = 0
    for j in range(i, len(panel_name)):
        if panel_name[i] == panel_name[j]:
            test = test + 1;
            circuit_name[panel_name[j]] = test
        else: continue
```

Но в словаре невозможно использовать ключи с одинаковыми значениями! Как быть?

Comment: А что вы дальше то с этим словарём делать хотели? От этого зависит какой ответ вам дать. Если вкратце, то вся суть словаря именно в уникальности ключей, чтобы быстро можно было искать значения по ключу. Вы собираетесь потом что-то искать по ключу "ЩК1.3: 2", например?

Comment: `Но в словаре невозможно использовать ключи с одинаковыми значениями! Как быть?` - не использовать словарь, или не пытаться хранить несколько значений с одинаковыми ключами. Как вариант, можно по одному ключу хранить список значений, т.е. словарь такого вида: `{'ЩК1.1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ЩК1.2': [1, 2, 3], 'ЩК1.3': [1, 2]}`

Comment: Другой вариант - хранить в словаре ключи в виде кортежей `('ЩК1.1', 1), ('ЩК1.1', 2), ...`

Comment: @CrazyElf при таком варианте не понятно что хранить в значениях, и тогда уже имеет смысл заменить словарь на список или множество.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы был список с нумерациями, порядком как в первом списке

Comment: Если использовать вариант {'ЩК1.1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ЩК1.2': [1, 2, 3], 'ЩК1.3': [1, 2]}. Как тогда добавлять цифры в словарь чтобы они не повторялись?

Comment: Или хотя бы узнать сколько элементов ЩК1.1, сколько элементов ЩК1.2 в списке и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, зачем это нужно. Ключи в словаре должны быть уникальны, в этом весь смысл словаря. Если вам просто посчитать элементы, то это легко сделать используя `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

panel_name = ["ЩК1.1", "ЩК1.1", "ЩК1.1", "ЩК1.1", "ЩК1.2", "ЩК1.2", "ЩК1.2", "ЩК1.3", "ЩК1.3"]

counter = Counter(panel_name)
print(counter)
```

Вывод:

```
Counter({'ЩК1.1': 4, 'ЩК1.2': 3, 'ЩК1.3': 2})
```

Потом можно легко напечатать из счётчика список идентификаторов в том виде, как у вас в примере:

```
for k,v in counter.items():
    for i in range(v):
        print(f'{k}: {i+1}')
```

Вывод:

```
ЩК1.1: 1
ЩК1.1: 2
ЩК1.1: 3
ЩК1.1: 4
ЩК1.2: 1
ЩК1.2: 2
ЩК1.2: 3
ЩК1.3: 1
ЩК1.3: 2
```